# Has anyone used a pop up for login or authentication using AAD?

Tags: authentication, popup, azure-active-directory

We run into an issue when try to use the `window.document` on the pop-up screen.

Basically, we are trying to authenticate a user using `AAD` from javascript and a pop-up screen, but we get an `Access denied` when try to access the new pop up.

Answer (score 0):

From the version of 1.0.12, the azure-activedirectory-library-for-js library already support for Login using a pop-up instead of a full redirect. Please see this: [#60](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/60)

I suggest that you use the latest version of azure-activedirectory-library-for-js to fix this issue. And to use the pop-up to authenticate, we need to add the parameter with `popUp:true` when initialize the `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider`.

Comment: While using this in the callback while trying to access the secondary window to check the redirect uri, the access denied and it cannot be verified.